# How to get the list of all files in my drive with specific extension?

Tags: c++, winapi, path-finding

Hello Guys I am newbie here. After long hopeless search I wanted to post this problem:

I am developing a C++ program that recurses over all folders and sub-folders searching for a specific file types.

First the function `FindFiles(string, string, bool)` works like a charm but the second form of it `FindFiles(struct var)` Doesn't work fine: It doesn't iterate over all folders and sub-folders.

In fact I need the second form because as the fact that the search may be too long I need to create a thread with the API `CreateThread`and pass my `arguments struct` to it as `LPVOID`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



// Arguments struct
struct args{
    string strDir;
    string strFilter;
    bool bRecurse;
};


void FindFiles(string strDir, string strFilter, bool bRecurse);
void FindFiles(args);


int main(){

//  FindFiles("D:", "*.mp3", true); // works fine

    args ar;
    ar.bRecurse  = true;
    ar.strDir    = "D:";
    ar.strFilter = "*.mp3";

    FindFiles(ar); // doesn't work fine

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void FindFiles(string strDir, string strFilter, bool bRecurse = true){
    if(bRecurse)
        FindFiles(strDir, strFilter, false);
    strDir += "\\";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;

    string strFileFilter = strDir + (bRecurse ? "*" : strFilter);
    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(strFileFilter.c_str(), &wfd);

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        return;
    else{
        if(!bRecurse)
            cout << strDir + string(wfd.cFileName) << endl;
        while(FindNextFile(hFile, &wfd) ){
            if(!bRecurse)
                cout << strDir + string(wfd.cFileName) << endl;
            else{
                if( (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) > 0 &&
                    wfd.cFileName[0] != '.')
                    FindFiles(strDir + string(wfd.cFileName), strFilter, true);
            }   
        }
    //  FindClose(hFile);
    }
}

void FindFiles(args ar){
    if(ar.bRecurse){
        ar.bRecurse = false;
        FindFiles(ar);
    }
    ar.strDir += "\\";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;

    string strFileFilter = ar.strDir + (ar.bRecurse ? "*" : ar.strFilter);
    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(strFileFilter.c_str(), &wfd);

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        return;
    else{
        if(!ar.bRecurse)
            cout << ar.strDir + string(wfd.cFileName) << endl;
        while(FindNextFile(hFile, &wfd) ){
            if(!ar.bRecurse)
                cout << ar.strDir + string(wfd.cFileName) << endl;
            else{
                if( (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) > 0 &&
                    wfd.cFileName[0] != '.'){
                        ar.strDir += string(wfd.cFileName);
                        ar.bRecurse = true;
                        FindFiles(ar);
                }
            }   
        }
        FindClose(hFile);
    }
}
```

Please pay a look at the second form because it is mine. I think there are some stupid mistakes there.

Any Help I do really appreciate it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In fact the first form I found it on somewhere in the internet so as you can see I edited it making the second form. However if you advise me some alternatives then I do really appreciate it. Thanx!

Comment: You are trying *way* too hard. Use a [recursive_directory_iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/recursive-directory-iterator-class) to do the job for you. Also, using ANSI/MBCS encoding for filenames on a file system that natively uses Unicode is a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable: Could explain more about the bug. Thanx for  the useful link.

Comment: NTFS stores file system entries using UTF-16 code units. An ANSI string cannot represent every UTF-16 encoded file name. Since the file system is outside your control, you cannot assume that your arbitrarily chosen code page will be good enough. Use `std::wstring` along with the Unicode versions of the API calls. Or `recursive_directory_iterator`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you for the information. I am a new here. would you recommend some unicode lessons?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 1-param version of `FindFiles()` doesn't recurse because it is modifying the `ar.bRecurse` flag so it is always false when searching for sub-folders:

```
void FindFiles(args ar){
    if(ar.bRecurse){
        ar.bRecurse = false; // <-- modified!
        FindFiles(ar);
    }
    ...
    // ar.bRecurse is still false here!
}
```

The 3-params version of `FindFiles()` does not do that:

```
void FindFiles(string strDir, string strFilter, bool bRecurse = true){
    if(bRecurse)
        FindFiles(strDir, strFilter, false); // <-- bRecurse is not modified here!
    ...
    // bRecurse is still the original value here!
}
```

The simplest solution is to reset `ar.bRecurse` back to true after that initial `FindFiles()` call:

```
void FindFiles(args ar){
    if(ar.bRecurse){
        ar.bRecurse = false; // <-- modified!
        FindFiles(ar);
        ar.bRecurse = true; // <-- reset here!
    }
    ...
}
```

Or use a temp struct for that call:

```
void FindFiles(args ar){
    if(ar.bRecurse){
        args arTmp = ar; // <-- temp copy!
        arTmp.bRecurse = false; // <-- modify the copy!
        FindFiles(arTmp);
    }
    ...
    // ar.bRecurse is still the original value here!
}
```

Now, with that said, you don't really need the `bRecurse` check at the top of the functions at all.  All it is really doing is scanning the input folder for only matching files, before then scanning the folder again to find only sub-folders.  You can accomplish the same logic by using a single search and locally caching the sub-folders to search next, eg:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Arguments struct
struct args
{
    string strDir;
    string strExt;
    bool bRecurse;
};

void FindFiles(const string &strDir, const string &strExt, bool bRecurse = true);
void FindFiles(const args &ar);

int main()
{    
    // FindFiles("D:", ".mp3", true);

    args ar;
    ar.strDir   = "D:";
    ar.strExt   = ".mp3";
    ar.bRecurse = true;

    FindFiles(ar);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void FindFiles(const string &strDir, const string &strExt, bool bRecurse)
{
    string strSearchDir = strDir;
    vector<string> vDirs;

    if (!strSearchDir.empty())
    {
        switch (strSearchDir[strSearchDir.size()-1])
        {
            case '\\':
            case '/':
                break;
            default:
              strSearchDir += "\\";
              break;
        }
    }

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA wfd = {};

    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFileA((strSearchDir + "*.*").c_str(), &wfd);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        return;

    do
    {
        string strFilename(wfd.cFileName);

        if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if ((strFilename == ".") || (strFilename == ".."))
                continue;

            if (bRecurse)
                vDirs.push_back(strSearchDir + strFilename);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!strExt.empty())
            {
                if (strFilename.size() < strExt.size())
                    continue;

                if (CompareStringA(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE, strFilename.c_str()+(strFilename.size()-strExt.size()), strExt.size(), strExt.c_str(), strExt.size()) != 2)
                    continue;
            }

            cout << strSearchDir << strFilename << endl;
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFile, &wfd));

    FindClose(hFile);

    if (bRecurse)
    {
        for(vector<string>::iterator iter = vDirs.begin(), end = vDirs.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
            FindFiles(*iter, strExt, true);
    }
}

void FindFiles(const args &ar)
{
    FindFiles(ar.strDir, ar.strExt, ar.bRecurse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you too much. I tried it and it works like a charm. You are too constructive. I'll check your whole code tomorrow I am too sleepy  now.

Comment: Yes really that was the problem When I modify `ar.bRecurse` it is always false in the sub-folders. But I didn't understand why?

Comment: So now can I pass `FindFiles(args)` to `CreateThread()` as the Start routine parameter?

Comment: One last thing that matters: If I pass `*.*` to list all the files with all extensions it doesn't work?